# ReactJS - Row select on parent table crashes nested tables

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, nested, react-functional-component, conditional-rendering

After quite some googling in the last week, I decided to ask you gentle people since I didn't seem to find anything that might be useful for my specific case.

The issue is related to the handling of state changes within nested function components although being myself not that experienced with ReactJS and coding in general I hope I can give you enough information about the problem.

Here's some pseudo code.

## Page structure

```
function Parent(props) {

     ...
     handleFilters()
     resetFilters()
     ...

     return(
          <div>
          <FirstTable filterTable={filters}/>
          </div>
}
```

### FirstTable

```
function FirstTable(props) {
        
        ...
        handleFilters()
        resetFilters()
         ...  
         useEffect {
                 APIcall(params).then((data) => {
                 if (data !== undefined) {
                 setTableData({
                ...tableData,
                 });
                }     
            });
          }, [props.filters, tableData.page, column]);
       }
      const onRowSelection = (e) => {
          APIcall_2(params).then((results)=>{ 
               setValues({...})
          }} 
       let toggledcomponent = (toggle) => {
             if (!toggle) {
                  return (
                      <div><p>message about no rows being selected</p></div>
                   );
            } else {
                 return (
                <div>             
                    <SecondTable filters={filters}/>
               </div>
               );
            } 
         };
return(
   <div>
      <div>
      <DataGrid(firstTable)
      onRowSelected = {(e) => {onRowSelection(e)}
      <Datagrid/>
      </div>
      {toggledcomponent(filters)}
   </div>
) }
```

## Issue

SecondTable has a very similar structure as FirstTable and calls for conditional rendering a toggled component in the exact manner as the first one, the second and third table are set for a useEffect to change when props of the relative parent change. ThirdTable's return contains only the Datagrid section.

#### Scenario 1

1. Page loads, first table is rendered.
2. RowSelect on first table triggers rendering of the conditional component which render second table.
3. Selecting new rows on first table successfully update the second one.

#### Scenario 2

1. Page loads, first table is rendered.
2. RowSelect on first table triggers rendering of the conditional component which render second table.
3. RowSelect on second table triggers rendering of the conditional component which render third table.
4. The selection of new rows on first table causes crash of page which slows down at first and then stops working with a multiple rendering depth exceeded.

I understand the question might seems unclear but assuming first and second table are exactly the same, why does the issue occur only when the third is open?

My goal here is that when I further trigger row select on first table, only the second is loaded and third should be disabled until a rowselection from the second table triggers displaying the "select a row message".

Thanks in advance and forgive me for the little clarity.

Comment: Please format your code when you get the chance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I added some indentation back, phone messed it up

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by setting state of toggle (which triggered the conditional rendering) to 0 or null for the tables that needed to be unmount and the setting state again to render them with the updated data. It's probably a poor workaround due to the many unnecessary renderings of parent component but it avoids the page from crashing completely.